# select nine story books from a pool of 12 books

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I am solving a quiz in where the questions seem as following:

**In how many ways Rafiq can select nine storybooks from a pool of 12 books where three are fiction, three are novels, three are comics, and three are thrillers?**

**i) 20 ii) 224 iii) 24 iv) 220**

So, I came up with the following solutions. Since Rafiq has to choose 9 books out of 12 books, so he can do this in 12p9 ways = 79833600 ways. Out of them, three are fiction, three are novels, three are comics, and three are thrillers.

So the way he can choose is 12p9/(3!*3!*3!*3!) = 3326400 ways. Is my solution is correct?

### update:

Three books in each category are identical

Comment: Your answer does not make sense.  If you simply want to select a subset of nine of the twelve books, you can do so in $\binom{12}{9}$ ways.

Comment: But out of 9 books, three are fiction, three are novels, three are comics, and three are thrillers. I have to consider this fact.

Comment: Are you saying you only care *how many* novels are chosen, not *which* novels are chosen?

Comment: I believe a clearer way to state it is that the three books in each category are identical

Comment: Yes, you are right. Three books in each category are identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Stars and bars* can be used very simply here with a slight twist

The original equation is $\;\;a + b+ c+d = 9,\;0\leq a ,b,c,d\leq3$

Put $A= 3-a,\;\; B = 3-b,\;\; C = 3-c,\;\; D=3-d,$
then $A+B+C+D = 3\;$ in the non-negative integers,

and the answer $ = \binom{3+4-1}{4-1} = \binom63 = 20$

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions in this answer:

1. The order that the books are chosen is irrelevant.
2. The 3 fiction books are indistinguishable from each other.  Ditto the novels, comics, and thrillers.

Your answer is wrong for two reasons:

1. Your ${}_{12}P_9$ basis assumes that the order that the books are selected is important.
2. Your attempt at a denominator-correction-factor of $(3!)^4$ is only applicable if there are exactly $3$ of each type of book chosen.  You can't have a universal correction factor, because you have to deal with different possible distributions of books.  For example, if you look in the this answer's Addendum, you will see three different possible distributions.

Therefore, I think that the whole approach of a denominator-correction-factor is problematic here.

---

There are generally two ways of attacking this problem: [Stars and Bars](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) which is also discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) and **generating functions**.

Since I am ignorant of how to apply generating functions, I will solve the problem using the Stars and Bars approach.

Let $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ represent the number of books selected from each of the 4 types.  Then, the problem reduces to computing the number of solutions, subject to the following constraints:

1. $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ are all integers.
2. $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ are all non-negative.
3. $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 9.$
4. $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ are each less than or equal to $3$.

The first thing to notice is that if constraint #4 above is ignored, then the number of solutions is 
$\displaystyle T_0 = \binom{9 + [4-1]}{4-1} = \binom{12}{3}.$

At this point, [Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) will be used to complete the problem.

Let $T_k$ denote the number of solutions where $k$ of the variables are **forced** to be greater than $3$.

Then, the final answer will be $T_0 - T_1 + T_2$, with $T_0$ already computed as $\binom{12}{3}$.

Note that it is impossible for there to be more than $2$ variables forced to be greater than $3$, because $4 + 4 + 4 > 9.$

The problem therefore has been reduced to :

- Computing $T_1$ and $T_2$.
- Then computing $T_0 - T_1 + T_2.$

---

I will use the phrase *bijects to* to represent that the number of solutions to 1 set of constraints equals the number of solutions to a second set of constraints.

$\underline{\text{Computation of }~ T_1}$ 
$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 9, ~x_1 \geq 4$ 
bijects to
$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 5, ~x_1 \geq 0.$

The bijected equation has $\binom{5 + [4-1]}{4-1} = \binom{8}{3}$ solutions. 
Therefore, since any of the 4 variables $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ can be the variable forced to be $> 3$, you have that  
$\displaystyle T_1 = 4 \times \binom{8}{3}$.

$\underline{\text{Computation of }~ T_2}$ 
$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 9, ~x_1 \geq 4, x_2 \geq 4$ 
bijects to
$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 1, ~x_1 \geq 0, x_2 \geq 0.$
The bijected equation has $\binom{1 + [4-1]}{4-1} = \binom{4}{3}$ solutions. 
Therefore, since there are $\binom{4}{2} = 6$ ways of selecting the $2$ variables from $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ that are to be forced to be $> 3$, you have that  
$\displaystyle T_2 = 6 \times \binom{4}{3}$.

$\underline{\text{Final Computation}}$

$$T_0 - T_1 + T_2 = \binom{12}{3} - \left[4 \times \binom{8}{3}\right] + \left[6 \times \binom{4}{3}\right].$$

---

**Addendum**
The final enumeration of $(20)$ may also be manually computed as follows:

$3-3-3-0$ : $(4)$ ways of choosing the omitted genre.

$3-3-2-1$ : $(4 \times 3) = 12$ ways of selecting the 2-genre and then the 1-genre.

$3-2-2-2$ : $(4)$ ways of choosing the 3-genre.

Answer (score 1):

Split the problem into three disjoint cases.

Case 1:

You choose from 3 categories. Number of ways to choose the 3 categories is 4C3. Once you have selected the categories, the books are fixed, so 4C3.

Case 2:

You choose from 4 categories. So 1 category must have 3 books, and the remaining 3 categories must have 2 books each. Once you choose the category with 3 books, all the rest of the books are fixed, so it is 4C1.

Case 3:

You choose 2 categories with 3 books and 1 category with with 2 books, the last category is fixed. So 4C2*2C1

Therefore total number of ways of choosing is 4C3+4C1+4C2*2C1=20

Since the number is so small, we can list them out.

Case 1:

3 fiction 3 novels 3 comics

3 fiction 3 novels 3 thrillers

3 novels 3 comics 3 thrillers

3 fiction 3 comis 3 thrillers

Case 2:

3 fiction 2 novels 2 comics 2 thrillers

2 fiction 3 novels 2 comics 2 thrillers

2 fiction 2 novels 3 comics 2 thrillers

2 fiction 2 novels 2 comics 3 thrillers

Case 3:

3 fiction 3 novels 2 comics 1 thrillers

3 fiction 3 novels 1 comics 2 thrillers

3 fiction 1 novels 2 comics 3 thrillers

3 fiction 2 novels 1 comics 3 thrillers

3 fiction 2 novels 3 comics 1 thrillers

3 fiction 1 novels 3 comics 2 thrillers

1 fiction 3 novels 3 comics 2 thrillers

2 fiction 3 novels 3 comics 1 thrillers

3 fiction 2 novels 3 comics 1 thrillers

3 fiction 1 novels 3 comics 2 thrillers

1 fiction 2 novels 3 comics 3 thrillers

2 fiction 1 novels 3 comics 3 thrillers

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted?